# Stacktrace does not include my class. What should I do?

Tags: java, swing, exception, stack-trace

I'm developing a Swing application that involves lots of classes and most times it works, while some times it crashes with a `NullPointerException`. When viewed in a console, the stacktrace does not include any of my classes. Because of this, I can't figure out where the origin of the problem is.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentInfo.setBounds(GroupLayout.java:3657)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(GroupLayout.java:928)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1508)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1497)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1693)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1628)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:691)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1679)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Based on the stacktrace I just want to know what could be the problem. I need ideas that will point me to the right direction. 
Thanks.

Comment: Most times? See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Any null component in container?

Comment: No I don't think so: @Sergey Lagutin

Comment: -1. Providing only the NPE without your code makes people guess about the problem. It won't be helpful neither to you nor future visitors and will probably cause unnecessary waste of your and other people's  time.

Comment: @dic19 I am using so many classes containing thousands of lines of code, the Exception does not indicate which class to even give me a clue on where the problem is. Which code do you want to see? And how will I know which code to provide?

Comment: @dic19 Since the question is "what should I do", I tried to write down strategies to follow in cases like this. I'm also hoping that in the long run it's more useful to learn "how to deal with situations like this?" than "what's specifically wrong in this very specific case?"

Comment: I see your point and I agree: guidelines and good practices are better than a very specific solution. But IMO that's valid for answers not questions. As a matter of facts I usualy like to focus not only in the very specific problem but other things that could be done in a better way as well. However by telling that you have a NPE but with no code it's not really helpful to anybody. Almost always there's something we can do before asking for help in the dark. @biziclop

Answer (score 3):

It's a tough job when that happens but there are two places you can start at:

1. Firstly, you can look at the source code of [`GroupLayout`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/javax/swing/GroupLayout.java?av=f), This reveals that the line in question is probably `int x = horizontalSpring.getOrigin();` (this may depend on your JDK version). This isn't terribly helpful but it's a start. If you look at where `horizontalSpring` is set, one thing immediately stands out: it's set to `null` in the `dispose()` method. So maybe your component is already disposed and that's why you're getting the error.
2. And secondly, you can place an exception breakpoint that stops execution when an NPE is thrown. Then you can check what exactly is null and what the value of everything else is. Hopefully it will also give you a clue as to why that thing is null, maybe it will confirm that the component is indeed disposed at this point.

A further clue is that you say **it works most of the time**. In the vast majority of cases this means some kind of threading/synchronization issue, maybe you're updating the component hierarchy from a thread that isn't the `Event Dispatcher`.

Comment: When you said "exception breakpoint" do you mean a try-catch block? If yes, where or which class do I put this? (now that my stacktrace does not show any of my classes).

Comment: @SamuelOkon No, in Eclipse (and I guess in every other IDE) you can add an exception breakpoint (in Eclipse it's `Run > Add Java Exception Breakpoint`), which will trigger when an exception of the specified type is thrown from anywhere in the code.

Comment: I have observed that when it crashes, the application freezes and there's nothing I can do than to terminate it from the console.

Answer (score 3):

The code for the `javax.swing.GroupLayout.ComponentInfo.setBounds` method is as follows:

```
    public void setBounds(Insets insets, int parentWidth, boolean ltr) {
        int x = horizontalSpring.getOrigin();
        int w = horizontalSpring.getSize();
        int y = verticalSpring.getOrigin();
        int h = verticalSpring.getSize();

        if (!ltr) {
            x = parentWidth - x - w;
        }
        component.setBounds(x + insets.left, y + insets.top, w, h);
    }
```

If a NPE is thrown by that method, then it follows that one (or more) of `insets`, `horizontalSpring`, `verticalSpring` or `component` is `null`.  (If we knew *precisely* which line the exception was thrown on, it would be possible to narrow this down to one or two possibilities.)

Going further than this is difficult without seeing your code, but I suspect that there is an error in the way that you have constructed a `GroupLayout`.

@biziclop's theory about updates is also plausible.  Swing's component data structures are NOT thread-safe, and should NOT be updated by any thread other than the swing event thread.